# Transforming coordinates using R - SWEREF to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, r, proj

I have some coordinated in SWEREF 99 TM which I cannot convert into WGS84 using the proj4 package in R.

```
temp <-  data.frame (x = c(598223, 598812, 598824, 598232, 597614, 597629), 
        y = c(7095460, 7095426, 7094827, 7094227, 7094821, 7095433))


ptransform(temp, 
    src.proj = '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ',
    dst.proj = '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs', silent=TRUE)
```

Note that the output is not equivalent to coordinates in Sweden - latitudes are equivalent to those near the equator.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to convert the coordinates using the `rgdal` package:

```
temp <-  data.frame (x = c(598223, 598812, 598824, 598232, 597614, 597629), 
        y = c(7095460, 7095426, 7094827, 7094227, 7094821, 7095433))


temp <- SpatialPoints (temp, proj4string = CRS ('+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'))
cord.WGS84 <- spTransform(temp, CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'))
```